# JSoup core web text extraction

Tags: java, jsoup

I am new to JSoup, Sorry if my question is too trivial.
I am trying to extract article text from http://www.nytimes.com/ but on printing the parse document
I am not able to see any articles in the parsed output

```
public class App 
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String url = "http://www.nytimes.com/";
        Document document;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            System.out.println(document.html()); // Articles not getting printed
            //System.out.println(document.toString()); // Same here
            String title = document.title();
            System.out.println("title : " + title); // Title is fine

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

ok I have tried to parse "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data" to retrieve the wiki data, same issue here as well I am not getting the wiki data in the out put.
Any help or hint will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For me it works, outputting the document via `System.out.println()` shows the html. What exactly to you mean with *Articles not getting printed*? Btw. PC or Mobile (eg. Android)? Any exceptions?

Comment: Hi Sorry for the confusion, I want to retrieve any text in <p class="summary">....... </p> tag in the web page. I have tried Elements paragraphs = document.select("p"); but its not returning any text. In fact I want to use whildcard no matter if class is present or not or with any value I should get the text for the tag <p .....>Text</p>  . Any hint will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to get all `<p class="summary>` text:

```
final String url = "http://www.nytimes.com/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

for( Element element : doc.select("p.summary") )
{
    if( element.hasText() ) // Skip those tags without text
    {
        System.out.println(element.text());
    }
}
```

If you need *all* `<p>` tags, without any filtering, you can use `doc.select("p")` instead. But in most cases it's better to select only those you need (see [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for Jsoup Selector documentation).